# Send InputStream from controller as image to gsp

Tags: grails, inputstream, gsp

I have InputStream of an image on controller.

```
InputStream fileStream
```

And I can render this fileStream as image on gsp using

```
render (contentType: 'image/jpeg') {
    response.outputStream << fileStream
}
```

But how I can send it to one existing .gsp view and show as image on page using img tag?

I tried to make

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg; ${fileStream}"/>
```

But it's don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src="${createLink(controller: 'controllerName', action: 'imageActionName')}"/>
```